# switch among conda installs

Tags: installation, conda, miniconda

At least in bash + conda v4.6.14, `conda init` adds the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/ebio/abt3_projects/software/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/ebio/abt3_projects/software/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/ebio/abt3_projects/software/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/ebio/abt3_projects/software/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

...so that the conda activation will occur during log in. This is great IF there is only one (mini/ana)-conda install on the file system.

I have multiple miniconda installs on the same file system, so how do I switch between them if only one install is set in the .bashrc file?

Sourcing an alternative conda setup (ie., `source ~/.bashrc_for_other_conda_install`) still keeps some of the initial `~/.bashrc` conda setup (eg., PATH info). I've been trying to figure out a way to do this with [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/326), but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: What is the use case of having multiple Mini/Anaconda installs?

Comment: There's a few that I can think of: 1) testing new base conda versions without affecting uses (eg., the big changes for >=4.4) 2) not flooding nb_conda with a bunch of developer conda envs (or just when running `conda info -e`)  3) adding/removing dev conda envs without having to worry that other users are using them. I'm surprised that more people don't use multiple installs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This sounds to me more like a sys admin question than a programming one, so I'm voting migrate it to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the initialization sections from your .bashrc, move them into separate bash files, and execute the one you want when you need it.

Alternatively, keep the section in .bashrc and wrap it in a function:

```
function delayed-conda-setup {
# >>> conda initialize >>>
...
# <<< conda initialize <<<
}
```

Then use `delayed-conda-setup` as required.